# postgreSQL - fill in blank date rows per ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a table which looks like this:

| ID | money_earned | days_since_start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 |
| 1 | 3000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2000 | 5 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 3 |

I want that rows, without a days_since_start (which means that the money_earned column was empty that day) - will include all the days PER ID, and fill the money_earned with last known value, so it to look like this:

| ID | money_earned | days_since_start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 |
| 1 | **2000** | **3** |
| 1 | 3000 | 4 |
| 1 | 2000 | 5 |
| 2 | 1000 | 1 |
| 2 | **1000** | **2** |
| 2 | 100 | 3 |

I have tried to look up for something like that, but I don't even know what function does that...

thank you!

Comment: Did you want to get `2 , 1000, 2` from your expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih yes, my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use CTE RECURSIVE with `OUTER JOIN` and `LAG` window function to make it.

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE
AS
(  
    SELECT ID,MIN(days_since_start) min_num,MAX(days_since_start) max_num
    FROM T 
    GROUP BY ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID,min_num+1,max_num
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE min_num+1 <= max_num
)
SELECT c.ID,
       CASE WHEN t1.ID IS NULL THEN LAG(money_earned) OVER(PARTITION BY c.ID ORDER BY c.min_num) ELSE money_earned END,
       c.min_num days_since_start
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN T t1
ON c.min_num = t1.days_since_start 
AND c.ID = t1.ID
ORDER BY c.ID
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6461419a5cc72524a6ada3bc8c1558e6)

Comment: I'm not sure i understood everything, but I'll try. thank you!